# Always On Availability Question mark

Tags: sql-server-2016, distributed-availability-groups

In my production environment I have two database Servers know as **DBN1** and **DBN2**. I have made a cluster between two and **DBN1** is my primary database server. Now I used Always on availability feature on both servers and databases were synchronized.

Today I am encountering an issue. There is a small question mark icon coming on the **DBN1** which is shown by **DBN2** always on availability properties. Moreover it is also not showing that it is a primary database. Why this is happening ?

This is my primary server output & follow the arrow

[image]

This is my secondary server output & follow the arrow

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The secondary replica does not know the role / status of that `DBN1` replica

**When trying to failover to the secondary, the status of the primary is not known:**

[image]

it finds the current primary replica but not the primary replica status.

When failing over from the primary it does find this information.

---

**When you select the properties of the replica with the question mark on the secondary replica:**

[image]

*Properties*

[image]

*Role: Unknown*

Whereas on the primary replica all roles and their sync states are known.

---

**sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states**

Executing this query returns multiple lines on the primary, but only the one for the secondary on the secondary replica's.

```
select * from sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states;
```

This behaviour would be reversed after failover.

---

**Extra checks**

When looking at the query that gets executed when opening the properties of the unknown replica on the secondary replica, the `sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states` dmv is also used with a `left join` in a much bigger query.

An interesting part here is the `OperationalState` column:

```
ISNULL(arstates.operational_state, 6) AS [OperationalState],
```

Meaning if the replica is not present in that dmv, such as when executing on the secondary, return `6` as the `OperationalState`.

This state is not explicitly noted in the documentation on the dmv:

> operational_state tinyint Current operational state of the replica,
>   one of:
>
> 0 = Pending failover
>
> 1 = Pending
>
> 2 = Online
>
> 3 = Offline
>
> 4 = Failed
>
> 5 = Failed, no quorum
>
> NULL = Replica is not local.
>
> For more information, see Roles and Operational States, later in this
>   topic.

The `'Unkown'` state is also not noted in the documentation.

In this case `6` is used when the role is not known.

It does not always appear to be `6`, when refreshing the availability replica's on the secondary:

[image]

**the query used sets the unknown replica's role status to 3:**

```
ISNULL(arstates.role, 3) AS [Role],
```

Which is offline on the dmv's documentation.

**And the connected state column will be `2`**

```
ISNULL(arstates.connected_state, 2) AS [ConnectionState],
```

Which is also not noted in the documentation:

> 0 : Disconnected. ...
>
> 1 : Connected. ...